# .htaccess to change the root to a different website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a already working website and now what I want another one of my domain to open the same website. `I don't want it to redirect to the previous website, I just want it to render the pages of the that website.` I am pretty new to htaccess and whatever I tried is redirecting to the previous website. I don't want the redirection. I just want that website to be shown without changing the url. here is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://www.example.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://www.example.com [L]
```

here, `project` is my new website which is hosted on my local server so I am able to open it without www or extension. I just need to code that can render the pages of example.com when I open `project`.

Comment: so set your new site's doc root to be the same as the old site, or put the new hostname as an alias of the old one. no need for any rewriting if the content is identical between the two.

Comment: No, 1st, both my sites are located on different servers. 2nd, after the basic rewritting is done, I will need to content changes depending on from which site the request is coming from, so I really need the rewritting.

Comment: rewriting is for local stuff only. if they're on separate servers, you'd need client-side redirects, e.g. `[R=301]` rules, and then the target server would only see that url. there might be referers available, but they're not reliable. you'd need to redirect to `example.com/oldsite` or something instead.

Comment: I still don't understand, can't I just show a different website when user requested for another without changing the url in their address bar?

Comment: not without proxying the new site's contents through your old one. if the address bar doesn't change in the browser, then the rewrite is done completely within apache. there'd be no clue to the client that the actual internal address is something different than what's requested. but you cannot do this with a different server - there's no way to silently make a browser point at site A but fetch site B's data for the user.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.. Will think for some different approach then.